# DateTime's representation in milliseconds?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a SQL-server timestamp that I need to convert into a representation of time in milliseconds since 1970. Can I do this with plain SQL? If not, I've extracted it into a `DateTime` variable in C#. Is it possible to get a millisec representation of this ?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: For the latter question: `(now - Epoch).TotalMilliseconds`, where `now` and `Epoch` are DateTime objects.

Comment: .NET has evolved: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You're probably trying to convert to a UNIX-like timestamp, which are in UTC:

```
yourDateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    ).TotalMilliseconds
```

This also avoids summertime issues, since UTC doesn't have those.

Comment: this gives a fraction as output, for example: "1552678714362.79" Where is the ".79" coming from?

Comment: @SharifYazdian It's exactly what you would expect, it's 0.79 milliseconds. The system time is measured in ticks. Given that 1 millisecond has 10000 ticks, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` store their values with higher precision than whole milliseconds. 0.79 ms = 7900 ticks. If you need a whole number, you can use `long ms = myTimeSpan.TotalTicks / 10000;`.

Comment: In .NET Core (>2.1) you can use `DateTime.UnixEpoch` instead of declaring the date.

Comment: This code has a problem: it assumes the `DateTime` (look the note in the contract of [`ToUniversalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime)) is in local time which it could be not. For example it's common to sample time with `DateTime.UtcNow` or it could be in another timezone.

Comment: @ceztko For `DateTime.UtcNow` this wouldn't be an issue, since the UtcNow DateTime has its Kind property set to Utc the `ToUniversalTime` method doesn't convert anything. If your DateTime is representing another timezone than local or UTC though, there might be an issue (but you are better off using DateTimeOffset rather than DateTime in those kind of situations anyway)

Answer (score 80):

In C#, you can write

```
(long)(date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: I suggest a cast to `long` instead of `int` :)

Comment: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(myDateAsALong);` If you want to go the other way.

Comment: @JackMorrissey: `AddMilliseconds()` expects a paramter of type `double`. An implicit conversion takes care of that, but it might be worth noting.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why do you suggest casting to long instead of int? :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: `int.MaxValue` in milliseconds is about 25 days. That's unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 53):

As of .NET 4.6, you can use a `DateTimeOffset` object to get the unix milliseconds. It has a constructor which takes a `DateTime` object, so you can just pass in your object as demonstrated below.

```
DateTime yourDateTime;
long yourDateTimeMilliseconds = new DateTimeOffset(yourDateTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

As noted in other answers, make sure `yourDateTime` has the correct `Kind` specified, or use `.ToUniversalTime()` to convert it to UTC time first.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) you can learn more about `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() doesn't actually exist in .Net 3.5.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx), `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` is available since .NET 4.6

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The OP is asking about a timestamp pulled from a database, so your comment about `.Now` doesn't directly apply to this question.

Answer (score 4):

There are `ToUnixTime()` and `ToUnixTimeMs()` methods in *DateTimeExtensions* class

`DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMs()`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(S, '1970-01-01', SYSDATETIME()) AS BIGINT) * 1000
```

This does not give you full precision, but `DATEDIFF(MS...` causes overflow.  If seconds are good enough, this should do it.

Answer (score 2):

This other solution for covert datetime to unixtimestampmillis C#.

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long GetCurrentUnixTimestampMillis()
{
    DateTime localDateTime, univDateTime;
    localDateTime = DateTime.Now;          
    univDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    return (long)(univDateTime - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer of Andoma, this is what I'm doing

You can create a Struct or a Class like this one

```
struct Date
    {
        public static double GetTime(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        public static DateTime DateTimeParse(double milliseconds)
        {
            return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();
        }

    }
```

And you can use this in your code as following

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

double total = Date.GetTime(dateTime);

dateTime = Date.DateTimeParse(total);
```

I hope this help you