# Set Datetimepicker date NaN

Tags: c#, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker and i save the date selected with a Save Button in my SQLServer with this code. For some reason i need to have a nullable DateTime:

```
clienteAdd.DataLead = string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["dataLead"]) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(form["dataLead"]);
```

The save function works fine, the problem is when i set the datetimepicker loaded. I recover the data from SQLServer with this code:

```
var elemento = new{ dataLead = clienteLead.DataLead }
```

I sent 'elemento' to the view from JQuery and i set the datetimepicker:

```
$('#dataLead').datepicker('setDate', (new Date(result.dataLead)));
```

When i set 'dataLead' i have NaN as date. I know the problem is the conversion of datetime but i don't know how to save and after load this data.

Thanks to all

Comment: So what's the value of `result.dataLead` that fails?

Comment: What's the point to cast `null`?

Comment: I want null because is a field not obbligatory. How can i pass this data to result.datalead?

Comment: My question was more, why did you wrote `(DateTime?)null` instead of `null`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), Javascript's Date object can recive either `milliseconds` which is a number or a `dateString`. My guess is that `result.dataLead` is an object since you `DataLead` is an object (a c# DateTime). That's why you can't do the assignment you want.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955901/4890123) explains how to get the millis from a `DateTime`.

Try the following code (untested):

```
var elemento = new{ dataLead = (long)clienteLead.DataLead.TotalMilliseconds }
```

and then do the regular assignment:

```
$('#dataLead').datepicker('setDate', (new Date(result.dataLead)));
```

Update:

Since `clientLead.DataLead` can be null you have to make sure you won't get a `NullPointerException` when doing `(long)clienteLead.DataLead.TotalMilliseconds` and maybe consider checking that `typeof result.dataLead != "undefined"` in the javascript