# C# UTC time as Milliseconds

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

In C# I would like to get UTC (+00:00) time as milliseconds. So I can use this in Javascript with offset(like below). I have tried several things but I did not achieve this.

```
new Date(1528204115692 - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toString()
```

Below code gives me milliseconds according to my timezone.

```
((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

I want to keep UTC time millisecond in db so I can show datetime according to user browser regional zone.

For example : in +03:00 zone now time is 06.05.2018 16:12:20.568

I want keep UTC zone time in milliseconds. (epoch time 00:00)

Can you Help?

Thank you

Comment: Javascript uses milliseconds starting from 1970/1/1 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp . It is a little more complex.

Comment: Are you looking for DateTime.UtcNow ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime's representation in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955883/datetimes-representation-in-milliseconds)

Comment: I don't know why this got 2 downvotes, it's a reasonable question. Maybe include some code next time.

Comment: In JS I wanto use this method:

new Date(1528204115692 - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toString()

Comment: @JeremyThompson It would be a reasonable question if he wrote some contest. Does he want to round `DateTime.UtcNow`, or does he want `DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)` (he is speaking of Javascript), or perhaps he wants ???

Comment: also, he didn't shown any attempt to achieve that

Comment: Unclear `((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` what problem it has. It is even shorter than my code :-)

Comment: Am I wrong? I am using in C# `((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` and I want to prove that in JS `new Date(1528204115692 - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toString()`

Comment: You are wrong, yes.  You should not be subtracting any offset.  The value you have from C# is in UTC, and the `Date` constructor in JavaScript takes its values in UTC.  Unix Timestamps are *always* in terms of UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Your C# code was correct.

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> new Date(value);
>
> value
>
> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

So you only need:

```
var date = new Date(1528204115692);
```

Where `1528204115692` is the value you obtain from your C# code.

Javascript dates are internally in milliseconds (it is simply a number) and "start" at 01 jan 1970 00.00 (that is "time" 0).

So:

```
public static readonly DateTime Date01Jan1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

public static long MillisecondsFrom01Jan1970(DateTime dt)
{
    return (dt.Ticks - Date01Jan1970.Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
}
```

Use it like:

```
long ms = MillisecondsFrom01Jan1970(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

This will return the number of ms that passed between the `DateTime.UtcNow` (the "now" in Utc time) and the 01 jan 1970.

Comment: Let me ask, your JS code gives the same result either in Russia or UK?
`var date = new Date(1528204115692);`

Also these C# codes are giving the same result, is not it wrong?

`((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();`
`((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();`

Comment: @barisusanmaz `new Date(1528204115692).toString()` will print differently depending on the local timezone, but internally it will be the same. For example in Italy it print: `Tue Jun 05 2018 15:08:35 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)`. And probably the method is compensating for the `DateTimeKind`, e.g. `DateTime.Now.Kind`, that saves the type of `DateTime`, if local or utc.

Answer (score 0):

The code below behaves differently for different time zones on users' browsers.

```
var date = new Date(1528204115692);
```

You can test it with the same number (millisecond) by changing computers time zone. This code shows different datetimes when changing time zone.